# Python3: List returning none type, so I can't iterate over it in a latter function

Tags: python, list, nonetype

```
def randomSet (n, up):

    """Build a random 'set' of integers.

    >>> randomSet(4, 10)
    [5, 3, 2, 8]

    Params: 
        n (int): # of integers in the set
        up (int): upperbound 
    Returns: (list) random 'set' of n integers between 0 and up, inclusive
    """

    A = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        randomInt = randrange(0, up)

        def checkDuplicates (randomInt):
            if randomInt not in A:
                A.append(randomInt)
            else:
                randomInt = randrange(0,up)
                checkDuplicates(randomInt)

        checkDuplicates(randomInt)

    return A
```

I've read a couple of answers and it was usually someone doing something along the lines of A = A.append(randomInt) which returns nonetype, but I can't figure out why mine is.
Edit: If I try to print the list it does. But if I type(A) it returns none and doesn't allow me to iterate over it in another function.

The problem occurs when I run this bit of code.

```
def printSet (A):

    """Print a 'set', using standard set notation.

    >>> printSet ([1,2,3,4])
    {1, 2, 3, 4}

    >>> printSet ([[1,2], [1,3]]
    {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}

    Params: A (list): set of integers, represented internally as a list
    """
    newSet = set()
    for a in range(len(A)):
        if A[a] not in newSet:
            newSet.add(A[a])
        else:
            printSet(A)

    print(A, end='')
```

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
^ Points to: for a in range(len(A)):

Comment: Try doing 'lst = randomSet (n, up)'

Comment: I tried `print(randomSet(4, 10))` and I'm getting `[9, 6, 7, 2]` just fine. And `print(type(randomSet(4,10))` gives `<class 'list'>` as expected. How are you calling `randomSet`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: A = randomSet (5, 100), but in the latter function I am trying to iterate over the list, and add the contents to a new set.

Comment: I suggest that you learn some debugging skills. Use https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to help you get started.

Comment: You still haven't shown us the code that has the problem. You have one function that correctly returns a list, and one function that correctly takes a list, but not the code that hooks them up—and that's the code where the bug probably is. For example, if I do `x = randomSet(4, 10); printSet(x)`, it works just fine. If I do `x = randomSet(4, 10); x = None; printSet(x)` I get your error.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) for `set()`? It completely automates a lot of your code. For instance, you don't need to check for duplicates, because `set([1,1,1,2])` simply returns `{1,2}`.